# Недопустимые символы после конверирования в base64

Tags: php, html, postgresql, base64

записываю в базу вот так:

```
$tmpfile_contents = file_get_contents($tmpfile->tempName/*это временный файл который я загрузил*/);
$this->data = base64_encode($tmpfile_contents);
```

поле в базе имеет тип TEXT (база postgres)

вот так вывожу:

```
$data = base64_decode("data:image/png;base64, ".$mdl->data/* это строка полученая из базы*/);
--------
<img src='<?php echo $data; ?>'>
```

и получаю крякозяблы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проверяю на наличие запрещенных в base64 символов

```
var_dump(base64_decode("data:image/png;base64, ".$mdl->data, true));
```

и получаю **FALSE** , что в свою очередь говорит о наличие таких запрещенных символов. Но ведь я кодировал то стандартным **php алгоритмом**, откуда они взялись?

Comment: Это `"data:image/png;base64, "` в base64_decode() зачем нужно? Как функция может данную подстроку декодировать?

Comment: @Visman и без нее пробовал тож самое

Comment: И зачем вы данные полученные из базы декодируете, если в src вы должны вставить кодированные данные?

Comment: В src ставите `"data:image/png;base64,".$mdl->data` и не занимаетесь ерундой ;)

Comment: @Visman работает. я думал что после кодирования в base64 их декодировать надо будет. а кодирование для хранения нужно. в общем то спасибо за помощь.